# Adding onchange event to FormHelper forms

Tags: javascript, cakephp, forms, cakephp-2.2

I've got a form full of checkboxes, and I'm trying something to update the form options via AJAX (as one option is selected other selections are limited). I had this working via submit buttons, but I'd like to get it done onchange for the select boxes. (Yes I know it's an unusual use of submitting a form).

I tried adding onchange to the input's attribute array, but it doesn't work. Other things like labels, classes etc all get applied fine, but onchange doesn't. Here's one of the checkbox lists:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Sale.LocationID', array(
        'label' => 'LocationID:',
        'options'=>$locations,
        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
        'onchange'=>"this.form.submit()",
        ));
```

Is there any way to add an onchange event to my checkboxes in a CakePHP standard manner, or will I have to build the checkboxes without Formhelper to do that?

Comment: Are you sure it's not?  I just tried your code in my app, and it added the onchange code just fine.  (I'm in 2.3.1, but I don't believe that would affect anything)

Comment: @Dave where in the HTML did the onchange end up? I didn't see anywhere from the parent div to the input tag and didn't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using inline event-handling is not very efficient, have you considered using jQuery and event delegation?

At the end of your view file;

```
// Using 'heredoc' here so we don't have to escape quotes
$script = <<< JS

    // this will handle click events on any checkbox on the page
    $(document).on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function(){
        // or AJAX post here
        this.form.submit();
    });
JS;  // note: must be at the start of the line, no space before JS

// Append the script to the buffer
$this->Js->buffer($script);
```

And just before the  inside your layout (e.g. default.ctp)

```
// output the JavaScript buffer
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

Comment: That *is* a much better idea actually, not sure why I didn't think of it...I'm doing that already on other forms too.

Comment: Hrm it doesn't submit via AJAX, which my submit button does; is that a different function?

Comment: How did you implement your AJAX submit? You need to either perform the AJAX-submit inside the click-handler or be sure to cancel the 'regular' form submit and perform an AJAX submit in stead

Comment: Nevermind, found the function I needed to use. I got too used to Cake's Js->Submit function I forgot how to make the function myself.